# How can I correct a wrong 'Personal Profile' address when enrolling in Apple Developer Program?

Tags: apple-id, developer-program

When enrolling in the iOS Developer Program as an individual, I reach a step "Review your enrollment information & submit". It shows an old address of my under "Personal Profile". You can see the old address (Durham, NC) below.

[image: Apple Developer Program Enrollment with old address]

I logged into [My Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com) to correct my old home address, yet My Apple ID shows an updated (correct) primary address. You can see the correct address (Renton, WA) below.

[image: My Apple ID with correct address]

So, how do I correct my personal profile address before I submit my iOS Developer Registration?

---

Additionally, I realize I can [Contact Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.html) to change my address *after* I am registered, but I would imagine things would be much faster and more streamlined if I correct the address *before* I finish my registration.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it. Don't know why, but I know how.

During the enrollment process, I had logged into [My Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/) to fix my address (only to find out that it was already correct there). Then, I opened up iTunes then went to the menu item Store > View Account. Once again, my address was correct there too, so I exited out of there.

From there, I decided to cancel the Developer Program enrollment, to which the Apple site replied that it had saved my enrollment-in-progress. I started the enrollment over again (though it had much of my previous information retained).

At that point, it had corrected the address by itself.

**In short: log in to [My Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/), then View Account on iTunes, cancel enrollment then [restart enrollment](https://developer.apple.com/ios/enroll/index.action).** Fixed (for me, at least).